# HorizontalScrollView custom adapter?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, custom-adapter

I'm trying to make a `Gallery` widget using `HorizontalScrollView`, So inside the `HorizontalScrollView` I add `ImageView`s, and the problem is that I'm going to add 600+ images!
Can I make some kind of a custom adapter in order to override the `GetView` method and utilize `convertView` in order to make the app smoother and avoid adding 600+ views at the same time?

Comment: Gallery is deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HorizontalScrollView` can contain only one `View`, so you have to draw that whole `View` anytime you are drawing any part of it. This could, however, be worked around by

1. extending `ViewGroup` as child of your `HorizontalScrollView`
2. using your custom adapter in that `ViewGroup` and call `getView()` and recycle on your own, drawing only Views that are currently visible in your `HorizontalScrollView`

**But this would take a lot if your time**. I'd at least try something like [`HorizontalListView`](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/tree/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui) first. A how-to of that specific class can be found [here](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34).