# Horizontal scrolling images gallery in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on camera application in android and have a page with a camera preview on half of the screen and an image gallery as shown in image below. Right now, i am using gridview to show image thumbnails in gallery. But, the problem is, i can't make the gallery scrollable(horizontally). I also found that horizontal scrolling is not supported in grid view.

[image]

The screenshot i provided is from iphone app and that is working fine. I used uicollectionview in iphone app for the same.

I can't find anything like uicollectionview in android.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: GridView does support scrolling and comes with a scroll bar.

Comment: That's what i already mentioned in my question.

Comment: have you tried horizontal listview, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use additional plugins like [this](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo)

Comment: Thank you very much. I really need something working like this. I even found my mistake with your help. :)

Comment: One more question Can i use adapter with horizontalScrollview to load images dynamically ?

Comment: i think it is better answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880340/horizontalscrollview-custom-adapter

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) if that is what you meant. Just take not that it recently got deprecated and you should either use a `HorizontalScrollView` or a `ViewPager` and programmatically add the items.

Comment: I even tried HorizontalScrollView but find no solution. And with ViewPager we can show one image at a time but i need multiple images as shown in image.